# Can I cast a map with a non-const value type to one with a const value type?

Tags: c++, stl

I have something like the following:

```
map<int, StructType> map;
const map<int, StructType>& GetMap() { return map; }
```

I'd like to do something along these lines:

```
const map<int, const StructType>& GetConstMap() { return map; }
```

Is there any way I can add this `const`-ness to the value type of the map?

Comment: You're returning a copy either way, so does it matter if it's `const`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to make it a reference. Fixed.

Comment: A `const map` implicitly **does** have a `const` value type.

Comment: Even so, returning a map with a const value shouldn't be necessary. All the member functions that give you non-const access to map values are also non-const, and thus can't be called on a const reference. The only way would be to cast away the `const`.

Comment: If the return reference was non-const but you wanted constness on `StructType` I guess you _could_ always use `reinterpret_cast` if it became necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface of `std::map` is designed so that `const map<K,T>` effectively has a const value type, by never exposing non-const access to its elements.

So you cannot add, remove or modify elements through a `const map` reference.

So:

```
struct X
{
    map<int, StructType> m;

    const map<int, StructType>& GetConstMap() const { return m; }
}
```

Is what you want.